# Probability map of an image

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

Probability map of an image can be calculated as bellow, may be it help someone

1

We have a probability matrix which has probabilty for each class. Let this be 
x=[x1 x2 x3 x4]    for 4 classes

2

to get probability map we will have four separate images for each class. let for class x1
x1=x1*255. this will be the pixel value for labeling.

3

Now for each class we will multiply this 255 with each probability value and will set value in the image this one.

4

as a result we will have four gray scale images and these are called probability maps.

Comment: I think your question is too broad. Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I ave to clasify each pixel of the face from either of six labels(mouth,nose,hair etc). As a result after classification i will have a color image with six colors assigning to each part of the face. I did this part of the project and now i have an image with just six colors. I am using random forest classifier which output is a probablility vecotr of all the six classes. I assign to each part label based on this probability vector. for example if position 1 value in this vecotr is maximim then pixel will have label 1. I have to make now probablty map for each image whch i am not understanding.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. You should ask your prof more details of what he wants. You can generate 6 probability maps, each of which represents of a class. Or you can generate a single probability map, each pixel value of which stands for probability of selected class for the pixel.

Comment: He asked me to generate six probability maps separate for each class. Can you give me a clue how can I do that. My prof told me it will be a grayscale image for each class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate 6 maps for all classes. Or you could select 6 different colors, and use the probability to interpolate a new color, then you will get just one map.

Comment: My final image already has six colors assign to each pixel. Like nonface part is assigned red, hair black, eyes green etc. Now my prof told me to make probability map for any of these images. He told me it will be a grayscale image. i searched alot on internet but i did not find any useful material.

Comment: I thought it should be something like heat map. You could Google 'probability map' and see the image results. I thought it's should be a color image, else I have no idea either.